# Como extraer datos de json en una URL con fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, javascript-objeto

tengo que obtener los datos de la URL que aparece en el fetch, pero los datos estan en arrays dentro del JSON y solo me trae uno solo, ¿como podria obtener todos los datos y hacer que recorra completo el objeto?

```
//Se llama la API con Fetch

fetch('https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property?access_token=6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {
    let resultados = json.value;
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    for(i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < resultados.Media[i].length; j++){
            container.innerHTML = `
            <div>
                <img src="${resultados[i].Media[j].MediaURL}">
            </div>`;
            console.log(i, j);
        }

    }
    console.log(resultados);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte de la concatenación, el problema es que estás usando mal el índice para recorrer 'Media': `for(j = 0; j < resultados.Media[i].length; j++)`, debería ser `resultados[i].Media.length`.

Sin embargo, te recomiendo usar [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) en lugar de `for`, para simplificar tanto el ciclo como la forma de acceder a cada propiedad.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
fetch('https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property?access_token=6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {
    let resultados = json.value;
    let html = '';
    resultados.forEach(res => {
        res.Media.forEach(media => {
            html += `
            <div>
                <img src="${media.MediaURL}">
            </div>`;
        });
    });
    container.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
/* Solo para poder ver las imágenes */
img { max-width:200px; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Por cierto, no es recomendable modificar el HTML de un elemento dentro de ciclos, porque en cada iteración obligas al navegador a interpretar nuevamente el contenido. Es mejor crear una variable, llenarla en el ciclo y, al final, asignarla al contenedor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa solución me ayudo muchisimo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu Array se ve bien con respecto al recorrido, lo que sucede es que en el inner html esta sustituyendo el contenido en cada vuelta y lo que necesitas hacer es acumularlo con `+=`.

En tu caso sería:

```
container.innerHTML += 
            '<div>
                <img src="${resultados[i].Media[j].MediaURL}">
            </div>';
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono, pero ahora me da este error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.Media[j] is undefined

Comment: uno de los problemas que tengo es que el array principal donde (resultados.length) tiene 10 elementos y el segundo de donde obtengo las imagenes (resultados[i].Media[j].MediaURL) el Media contiene 5 elemento, y no se como hacer que recorra los 10 y por cada iteracion recorra los 6 elementos de media